# Microsoft graph presence subscription throws exception: A task was canceled

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I am using Microsoft graph beta sdk for the presence subscription. And according to Microsoft, Subscription for multiple user are allowed and we can subscribe almost 650 user in one subscription.

> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/get-notified-of-presence-changes-the-microsoft-graph-presence-subscription-api-is-now-available-in-public-preview/

but in my scenario I am only able to subscribe 60 users at a time. If I increase the users to 70 then it will return an exception.

ExtensionError
Message: Operation: Create; Exception: [A task was canceled.]
Inner error:
AdditionalData:
date:
request-id:  xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx
client-request-id:xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx
ClientRequestId:  xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx

Is there any way I can increase the request timeout or any other solution.

Comment: Hi there, I would really appreciate it if someone can help me in this regard.

Comment: Can you still repro the issue? If yes, please share the requestid, timestamp, error of the Graph AI response.

Comment: I have checked and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Wonderful to hear that it's working. Sounds like a technical glitch/temporary issue that you might had during the time. In future if you see any issues, you can report it back here.